# Regex for non ANSI-style joins?

Tags: sql, regex

One of our rules is that all [database joins have to be ANSI-style](http://www.dba-oracle.com/oracle_news/2004_2_19_rittman.htm).  As part of our build process I would like to scan all joins committed to source control for violations.

I got a partial answer which I will post below but I'm sure its missing something and there must be a better one.

Here is a non-comprehensive list of examples

Should match:

```
SELECT * 
FROM cats, owners, dogs
WHERE cats.owner = onwers.id and owners.id += dogs.owner;


SELECT * FROM cats c, owners o WHERE c.owner = o.id;
```

Should not match:

```
SELECT *
FROM owners left outer join cats on (owners.id = cats.owner);

SELECT * 
   FROM owners inner join cats on (cats.owners = GetOnersOfTabbies(param1, parm2))
```

Comment: can you please post some old style examples?

Comment: I don;t know reg ex but i do want to point out a couple of test cases your reg ex should be able to catch, one is one where the old style joins are mixed with the ANSII standard ones in the same query. You also want to look at how it will handle a correlated subquery in a query with all ANSII joins

Comment: Regular expressions aren't going to work so well if there are joins to derived tables.

Comment: What flavor of DB and/or SQL_IDENTIFIER_QUOTE_CHAR?  Can you name a table, for instance, `"FROM foo, bar"` ?

Comment: That...would certainly be a problem...but given that its just a static analysis alert not a particularly big one.  I am mildly surprised actually that nobody seems to be running something like this already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, here I go:

```
FROM [\s\S]*?,[\s\S]*?WHERE
```

Will match a `,` between `FROM` and `WHERE` clauses even inside a multi line query.

`[\s\S]*?` means: take [smallest possible match](http://www.amk.ca/python/howto/regex/regex.html#SECTION000730000000000000000) for whitespace characters (including line-breaks) and non-whitespaces; this is also known as "non-greedy pattern".

Answer (score 1):

Here's my regex:

```
from\s+\w+(\s+)?(\w+)?,(\s+)?\w+
```

Ruben's answer didn't work for me in my regex tester.

```
\s     == space character
\s+    == 1+ space character(s)
(\s+)? == Within the brackets is optional, reqires a "?" immediately after the ")"
\w     == word character, alphanumeric
```

To catch `SELECT * FROM (cats c, owners o) WHERE c.owner = o.id;`, use:

```
from\s+(\()?\w+(\s+)?(\w+)?,(\s+)?\w+
```

You need to escape the bracket, using the `\` character:

```
(\()?  == '(' character
```

Comment: Hmm, won't catch something like: SELECT * FROM (cats c, owners o) WHERE c.owner = o.id;

Answer (score 0):

Here is my attempt:

```
FROM (\s*\S+\s*(\w\s*)*,)+
```

Should pick up the first comma in a from clause - these are necessary for old style joins.

Comment: you could to add this into your question, as you already tried this before

Comment: If you view stack-overflow as programmer tech-support yes, if you view it as a 'repository of programming knowledge' then it belongs in answers.  It is after all a valid answer, just not (I suspect) a particularly good one. I'm actually hoping a better one gets voted past it.

Comment: I think in this case, it would have been more clear to put it in the question.  That way we know what you have tried without having to look for your name in the answers.